# Testing order in serialized object in Rails with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to test the order of serialized object for index action in request specs. The controller index action have this code:

```rb
def index
  user_platforms = current_user.user_platforms.order('created_at desc')

  render json: UserPlatformsSerializer.new(user_platforms),
         status: :ok
end
```

Usually when I am testing the serialized object in response I do:

```rb
# request spec
let(:user) { create(:user) }
let(:user_platforms) { create_list(:user_platform, 5, user: user)

it 'return user platforms in response' do
  expect(JSON.parse(response.body)).to eq(UserPlatformsSerializer.new(user_platforms).serializable_hash.as_json)
end
```

But since I need it in a specific order, so i need to prepare the expected value before assertion, so my attempt is:

```rb
it 'return ordered user platforms with created_at in the response' do
  expected = UserPlatformsSerializer.new(user_platforms)
    .serializable_hash.as_json['data']
    .sort_by { |h| h['attributes']['created_at'] }.reverse

  expect(JSON.parse(response.body)['data']).to eq expected
end
```

This works fine and the test passes, but it seems un-intuitive to write tests that way.
Also another problem with this test that it depend on the existence of `created_at` attribute in the serialized object, which I don't need it in my case and I have added it to the serializer only to make the test pass.

Is there any better way to test order in serialized objects?

I am using `jsonapi-serializer` gem.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
let(:user_platforms) do
  [
    create(:user_platform)],
    create(:user_platform, created_at: Time.current - 5.minutes)
  ] 
}
end
```

to provide objects in desired order to serializer in spec.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This will work, but how is this actually testing the order? The way I see it is that you are tricking the test.

Comment: If you really want to test order you should stop testing implementation and start testing behavior. You could do this by comparing, checking response without using serializer class at all.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when I need to test the order of the items in a hash, I just compare the expectation / given as JSON strings, because the comparison will then fail if the order is different:

```
expect(response.body))
.to eq(JSON.dump(UserPlatformsSerializer.new(user_platforms).serializable_hash))
```

A bit harder to maintain because it's harder to see differences this way, but it does not depend on any timestamp.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is similar to what I am doing above:
`expect(JSON.parse(response.body)).to eq(UserPlatformsSerializer.new(user_platforms).serializable_hash.as_json)`. But it still doesn't test the given order.

Comment: How's it similar? response.body is a string while JSON.parse(response.body) is a hash. How does it not test the order?

Comment: both are comparing the same thing whether it's hash or string. How `UserPlatformsSerializer.new(user_platforms).serializable_hash` ordering `user_platforms`? Note: i already tried your solution and the test didn't pass.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to pass `created_at` attribute on your serializer, since he's only used to order your query.

Rather create an "random" list of users, you can change the `created_at` field on each user that you create:

```
let(:user1) { create(:user, created_at: Time.current) }
let(:user2) { create(:user, created_at: Time.current - 5.minutes) }
let(:user3) { create(:user, created_at: Time.current + 5.minutes) }
```

With that, you already know the expected order that you want. So, you only need to check if your `response.body` is `eq` with the order [user3, user1, user2]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this doesn't test the order, you are passing the expected order to the serializer

Comment: I think it doest, since who is controlling the order is your `current_user.user_platforms.order('created_at desc')`, what the serializer will do is garantee that you are receiveing the expected output based on what you built.

Comment: That's right, but I am not testing the serializer, I am testing the the controller response in my request specs.